# Managed C++: How do I get my unmanaged verison number to match my assembly version number

Tags: version, managed-c++

I have a managed c++ project.

How do I make the version information of the DLL (as seen in explorer and used by installers) match the version information generated in the Assembly Version atttribute?

AssemblyInfo.cpp:

```
[assembly:AssemblyVersion("5.1.*")];
```

The problem is discussed [here](http://www.empowertec.de/blog/2008/02/03/version-information-in-managed-c-assemblies-in-visual-studio/).

Answer (score 0):

Also set the [AssemblyFileVersionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.aspx) and [AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute.aspx).

Comment: Will this magically translate into version information, even in a Managed C++ DLL?

Comment: It is documented (see linked pages) to do so. There is nothing giving exceptions. If the C++/CLI doesn't follow, would be a good reason to a comment to MSDN :-)

Comment: This does not help me. The file version still isn't shown in Explorer -> Properties -> Version Information of the file

Comment: Found working answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204774/how-do-you-set-the-version-of-a-c-cli-project-in-visual-studio