# How to add commit hash to details of an executable file using GitVersion

Tags: c#, git, gitversion, assemblyinfo, pre-build-event

In [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69371809), I asked how to add a commit hash to an executable file, built in Visual Studio.

I'm almost there: I have decided to use `GitVersion` and this tool indeed modifies the `AssemblyInfo.cs` files of my Visual Studio project, causing some interesting information being added to the "Details" tab of my executable file.
I'm quite confident that, by filling in the `GitVersion` commands in my project's Build Events (Pre-build event command line), I might be able to automate this.

Now there just are some small things to take care of, as you can see here:

`GitVersion` command and result:

```
Command Prompt> dotnet-gitversion /updateassemblyinfo

{
  "Major": 0,
  "Minor": 1,
  "Patch": 0,
  ...
  "InformationalVersion": "0.1.0-develop-own.1+101.Branch.develop-own.Sha.99560ad4873ab9e04bb8f262aafb5b3ee2fb6c1e",
  "BranchName": "develop-own",
  ...
  "Sha": "99560ad4873ab9e04bb8f262aafb5b3ee2fb6c1e",
  "ShortSha": "99560ad",
  ...
  "CommitDate": "2022-04-25"
}
```

Previous version of `AssemblyInfo.cs` (before running `GitVersion`):

```
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Current version of `AssemblyInfo.cs` (after running `GitVersion`):

```
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("0.1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("0.1.0-develop-own.1+101.Branch.develop-own.Sha.99560ad4873ab9e04bb8f262aafb5b3ee2fb6c1e")]
```

You can see how the "Product version" in the details tab of the compiled file gets filled in with the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` value, while I want this to be a combination of other information, like `AssemblyVersion`, combined with `Sha` or even with `ShortSha`:

[image]

Let's face it: I can launch `GitVersion` but I have no clue how to configure its results and `GitVersion /?` seems not to be very helpful.
Does anybody know how to do this?

**Edit after some more insight:**
In the meantime I've understood how to get specific information:

```
dotnet-gitversion /showvariable "ShortSha"
28c8531
```

But the following question pops up: when looking at the first items (major, minor and patch) the documentation mentions:

```
{
  "Major": 3,
  "Minor": 22,
  "Patch": 11,
  ...
```

Where is `GitVersion` getting this information from?
(Just as a stupid test, I created a new branch `test/4.0.0.0`, but this did not alter the `Major` value in the `GitVersion` result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is GitVersion getting this information from?

The short answer is, it depends :-)

GitVersion uses the history of the git repository, using a combination of commit messages, tags, branch names, configuration file, in order to assert the current version number.

You can see this documented here:

https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/version-sources

On top of this, depending on what [branching strategy](https://gitversion.net/docs/learn/branching-strategies/) you are using, and what [configuration](https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/configuration) you have set up, GitVersion will assert the semantic version number for your repository.

If you run the [command](https://gitversion.net/docs/usage/cli/arguments):

```
dotnet-gitversion /diag
```

You should be able to see in the output how GitVersion asserted the base version for the repository, and how it then calculated the remaining portions of the version number.